# How to analyse the memory usage of Mongo DB in windows operating system?

Tags: database, mongodb

I have installed mongodb-win32-x86_64-3.0.6 in windows operating system. I want to analayse the memory usage by Mongodb at any given time.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The command db.serverStatus().mem will give the details like total allocated memory and currently used memory. The user needs clusterAdmin role to execute the serverstatus command.